# Phonegap Sqlite Order by Not Correct utf8 problems

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to SQL Ordering Data with Sqlite on Phonegap but results is not correct !
It would be : abcçdeéě

My Code:

```
db.transaction(function(tx){

        tx.executeSql('SELECT id,keyword FROM Glossary ORDER BY lower(keyword) COLLATE NOCASE',[] , function(tx, results){
            var lastAlpha = "*";
            for(i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
                var firstChr = results.rows.item(i).keyword.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
                if(firstChr!=lastAlpha){
                    console.log(firstChr);
                    lastAlpha = firstChr;
                }
            }
        },errorCB2);
    });
```

Result :

```
2012-11-22 17:14:14.641[15032:c07] [LOG] A
2012-11-22 17:14:14.641[15032:c07] [LOG] B
2012-11-22 17:14:14.642[15032:c07] [LOG] C
2012-11-22 17:14:14.644[15032:c07] [LOG] D
2012-11-22 17:14:14.645[15032:c07] [LOG] E
2012-11-22 17:14:14.646[15032:c07] [LOG] F
2012-11-22 17:14:14.647[15032:c07] [LOG] G
2012-11-22 17:14:14.648[15032:c07] [LOG] H
2012-11-22 17:14:14.649[15032:c07] [LOG] I
2012-11-22 17:14:14.650[15032:c07] [LOG] J
2012-11-22 17:14:14.651[15032:c07] [LOG] K
2012-11-22 17:14:14.652[15032:c07] [LOG] L
2012-11-22 17:14:14.654[15032:c07] [LOG] M
2012-11-22 17:14:14.655[15032:c07] [LOG] N
2012-11-22 17:14:14.656[15032:c07] [LOG] O
2012-11-22 17:14:14.657[15032:c07] [LOG] P
2012-11-22 17:14:14.658[15032:c07] [LOG] Q
2012-11-22 17:14:14.659[15032:c07] [LOG] R
2012-11-22 17:14:14.660[15032:c07] [LOG] S
2012-11-22 17:14:14.661[15032:c07] [LOG] T
2012-11-22 17:14:14.662[15032:c07] [LOG] U
2012-11-22 17:14:14.664[15032:c07] [LOG] V
2012-11-22 17:14:14.665[15032:c07] [LOG] W
2012-11-22 17:14:14.666[15032:c07] [LOG] X
2012-11-22 17:14:14.668[15032:c07] [LOG] Y
2012-11-22 17:14:14.669[15032:c07] [LOG] Z
2012-11-22 17:14:14.671[15032:c07] [LOG] Ç
2012-11-22 17:14:14.672[15032:c07] [LOG] É
2012-11-22 17:14:14.673[15032:c07] [LOG] Ö
2012-11-22 17:14:14.674[15032:c07] [LOG] Ü
2012-11-22 17:14:14.674[15032:c07] [LOG] İ
2012-11-22 17:14:14.676[15032:c07] [LOG] Ş
```

I've seen like "Latin Characters" at The Last. !
You Have Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation

> NOCASE - The same as binary, except the 26 upper case characters of ASCII are folded to their lower case equivalents before the comparison is performed. Note that only ASCII characters are case folded. SQLite does not attempt to do full UTF case folding due to the size of the tables required.

I believe it's saying that SQLite won't provide that kind of sorting because it would take too much processing time to achieve that. SQLite does provide an interface to definte your own collation sequences (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html) but I don't think that would be easily usable in PhoneGap.

If you are very determined to have this sorting, you could hack it a bit and do multiple queries that would query based on a 'starts with' type operator and then chain them all together in the desired order. But I cringe at the thought of actually trying to do that.